# Can I get the observable array I'm foreach-ing over inside?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

It's probably best to explain with an example.  [This](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenSanderson/wKRSu/light/) is an example linked from the Knockout blog on how to use `$parent`.  However, in this case, `$parent` is apparently the same as `$root`, so I'm having trouble seeing the benefit.

Where it says `$parent.lastUpdated`, I'd like to instead access the observable array, `this.products`.  I realize I could say `$root.products`.  However, I'd like to generalize this, rather than write it explicitly for every list.

I will actually be using this in conjunction with `ko.contextFor`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't get access (generically) to the observableArray that is being looped over directly inside of the foreach loop.

`$root` and `$parent` is about the scope, so it will just give you the object that contains the observableArray.

However, you can take advantage of this by ensuring that the scope is your observableArray by using the `with` binding.

If you just need the underlying array, then you can do:

```
<div data-bind="with: products">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <li>
            <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
            &mdash;
            Array length: <em data-bind="text: $parent.length"></em>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

If you really need the observableArray, then you need to make sure that it has not been unwrapped (in the above example `$data` is unwrapped already).  To do this, you can normalize the name of the array and look for it in your template like:

```
<div data-bind="with: { theArray: products }">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: theArray">
        <li>
            <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
            &mdash;
            Array length: <em data-bind="text: $parent.theArray().length"></em>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/T6JvV/

If you can't live with the extra `div`, then you can certainly use the containerless control-flow bindings like:

```
<!-- ko with: { theArray: products } -->
    <ul data-bind="foreach: theArray">
        <li>
            <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
            &mdash;
            Array length: <em data-bind="text: $parent.theArray().length"></em>
        </li>
    </ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thanks, both for the information that it can't be done, and for the `with` work-around.

Comment: There's a "minor" issue with this (solution 1 using "with" on the observable array).. The "with" causes redrawing of the child structure (I had to overwrite the logic of "with" to avoid this but out of the box I believe this is how it works upon mutation of the observable - same with if) leading to any non-bound elements to be reset - you may need bootstrap panels for example which are not bound. I'm on the quest of figuring this out - maybe setting a parent $context variable which gets cloned when child context is created so $context['myContextualArrayId'] is there..